# Connecting to a Microsoft SQL Database from ASP.NET web service

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, web-services, database-connection

I have been trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server through a web service in visual studio 2015. However, I am having difficulty trying to retrieve data from the database.

In my web config file, I have the following code:

```
<add name="SecondlyReadingsContext" connectionString="Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=SecondlyReadingsContext;user=sa;password=adminadmin2" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I assume(might be wrong) that the code above establishes a connection with the server and the database itself. I referenced the above code from the following link:
[Connecting to SQL server from Restful C# service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45558507/connecting-to-sql-server-from-restful-c-sharp-service?noredirect=1#comment78077666_45558507)

In my Model class, I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace HelloWorld.Models.APiModels
{
    public class SecondlyReading
    {

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int ChannelID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public float RMSVoltage { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public float Frequency { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public float RMSCurrent { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public float RealPower { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public float ReactivePower { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public float ApparentPower { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public float PowerFactor { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string DeviceId { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("DeviceId")]
        //public virtual Device Device { get; set; }

    }
}
```

In my Controller, I have this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using HelloWorld.Models;
using HelloWorld.Models.APiModels;

namespace HelloWorld.Controllers
{
    public class SecondlyReadingsController : ApiController
    {
        private SecondlyReadingsContext db = new SecondlyReadingsContext();

        // GET: api/SecondlyReadings
        public IQueryable<SecondlyReading> GetSecondlyReadings()
        {
            return db.SecondlyReadings;
        }

        // GET: api/SecondlyReadings/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(SecondlyReading))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetSecondlyReading(int id)
        {
            SecondlyReading secondlyReading = db.SecondlyReadings.Find(id);
            if (secondlyReading == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(secondlyReading);
        }

        // PUT: api/SecondlyReadings/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public IHttpActionResult PutSecondlyReading(int id, SecondlyReading secondlyReading)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != secondlyReading.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(secondlyReading).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!SecondlyReadingExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        // POST: api/SecondlyReadings
        [ResponseType(typeof(SecondlyReading))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostSecondlyReading(SecondlyReading secondlyReading)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.SecondlyReadings.Add(secondlyReading);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = secondlyReading.Id }, secondlyReading);
        }

        // DELETE: api/SecondlyReadings/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(SecondlyReading))]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteSecondlyReading(int id)
        {
            SecondlyReading secondlyReading = db.SecondlyReadings.Find(id);
            if (secondlyReading == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.SecondlyReadings.Remove(secondlyReading);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(secondlyReading);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool SecondlyReadingExists(int id)
        {
            return db.SecondlyReadings.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I have also been told that I am supposed to do some kind of database connection in the following SecondlyReadingContext.cs file, but I am not sure of how to go about it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace HelloWorld.Models
{
    public class SecondlyReadingsContext : DbContext
    {
        // You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
        // 
        // If you want Entity Framework to drop and regenerate your database
        // automatically whenever you change your model schema, please use data migrations.
        // For more information refer to the documentation:
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

        public SecondlyReadingsContext() : base("name=SecondlyReadingsContext")
        {   

        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<HelloWorld.Models.APiModels.SecondlyReading> SecondlyReadings { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I run my server through IIS manager and add api/SecondlyReadings to the url, I am supposed to get the data back in json format, however, I am not retrieving any data and it returns a blank page(in a notepad, as I run it in Internet Explorer). Would anyone tell me what I have done wrong in my code, or anything that I have missed out. I have been working on this for a while and would really appreciate any help.

For reference, this is the dummy data that I added into the Microsoft SQL server which I am trying to retrieve:
[image: Database Table]

My context file to after adding bindings:
[image]

Error after editing web.config file:
[image]

Updated result after editing web.config file
[image]

Comment: is `SecondlyReadingsContext` your model name?

Comment: Why api/Readings? Looks like it needs api/SecondlyReadings

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: It's secondly readings, just edited. Sorry for the confusion @DavidN

Comment: You need to modify your connection string. For models it also include few more details.

Comment: Yup, that is my model name@Ashikirsha

Comment: I had errors previously like 404 and 500 before I added in that code above in my web.config file. But right now there are no errors, main issue is that I cannot retrieve data @RePierre

Comment: Does your DB have data?

Comment: Modify connection string refers to the the code in the web.config file right? Also, what do you mean by models include a few more details? @QaiserMehmood

Comment: Yup it does have data. I added some dummy data in @DavidN

Comment: providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" add this@gram95

Comment: Is your DB named "SecondlyReadingsContext"? Initial Catalog should be the name of your Database.

Comment: Replace providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  with providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"

Comment: I think I made a mistake there, will change it @DavidN

Comment: What is the difference in sql and entity client? @QaiserMehmood

Comment: I added a photo above for the dummy data I added in @DavidN

Answer (score 0):

Set your tables binding here to get data

[image]

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

}
public virtual DbSet<SecondlyReading> SecondlyReadings { get; set; }
```

Remember to re-name your table name on SQL Server End. to SecondlyReading

Comment: It looks like he's using Entity Framework Code First, so SqlClient is right.

Answer (score 0):

Set Initial Catalog to the name of your Database. Right now it's set to SecondlyReadingsContext, which I assume isn't the name of your Database.

Comment: I have changed it though but still can't get any data. Do I need to add anything into the context file?

Comment: Can you show the name or your DB and what you're setting it ot?

Comment: <add name="SecondlyReadingsContext" connectionString="Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=cloudsql;user=sa;password=adminadmin2" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Do you have a DB named cloudsql at the host myserver?

Comment: changed the db name

Comment: You mean in Microsoft Sql server itself? If so, yes I do. And my table name is elecdata